# NiFi: "pipeline" or Input/Output ports between PG in different scopes?

Tags: input, output, port

We have a processor, lets say in "NiFi Flow">>"A">>"B">>"C" and we want to provide its output (lets say using an Output Port) to a (let say using an Input Port) which is in "NiFi Flow">>"1">>"2">>"3".

How can we connect those Input/Output ports on different levels / scopes on the same installation using the GUI?